# running a mysql query inside a loop of another without a sync error

Tags: mysql, c

If I have code like this (irrelevant things like initialising the connection and handle omitted):

```
MYSQL_RES *res;
MYSQL_ROW row;
mysql_query(mysql, "some select query");
res = mysql_use_result(mysql);
while (row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) {
    MYSQL_RES *res2;
    MYSQL_ROW row2;
    mysql_query(mysql, "some other select query using an id from the first");
    res2 = mysql_use_result(mysql);
    /* ... */
    mysql_free_result(res2);
}
mysql_free_result(res);
```

Whenever I run the second `mysql_query` (in the loop), I get the error

```
mysql: 2014: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

How can I run another select query while fetching rows from one select query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sent an email to the MySQL mailing list. Basically, to be able to do this, I need to have two independent MySQL connections. Thanks, Shawn Green (from Oracle).

> The mysql object you are using for your connection can only have one active query or result on it at a time. To have two sets of results working, you need a second independent connection to the MySQL server